# Where Do I Find The Cancellation Date For In-App Subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm finding it hard to retrieve a cancellation date (or check if someone's canceled at all) for an auto-renewable IAP subscription.

I'm doing receipt validation, but `cancellation_date_ms` never seems to be in the receipts response. I've tested this myself by creating a live subscription in production and canceling it myself, still no luck.

I've also tried using Apple's `Subscription Status URL` webhook, but they don't seem to send anything useful other than when somebody first subscribes or their subscription is renewed.

I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: Only Apple can immediately cancel a subscription at a user's request. If the user cancels the renewal then you simply don't get a renewal transaction at the end of the current period. The user continues to have a valid subscription until the end of the current period.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for that. What would be the case if user A subscribed and was given a 7 days free trial and canceled their own subscription straight away so it wouldn't renew? Is there any way of me telling when they had canceled?

Comment: No, you just don't get a renewal after the 7 days.

Comment: In Israel, South Africa, and Turkey, users can cancel a subscription made through the iTunes Store or the App Store with immediate effect ([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206627))